# Finding contour around a cluster of pixels

Tags: python, image-processing, contour

I have a set of images that look like this:

[image]

Using python need a way to find a contour around the yellow shape that ignores the isolated points and is not too complex. Something looking a bit like this :

[image]

I tried some methods such as the find_contours function from skimage,which gives this after keeping only the biggest contour:

[image]

which is not what I am looking for. A also tried active contour (snake) which had the problem of paying too much attention to isolated pixels. Is there a particular method that would help me in this situation ?

Thank you

Comment: You could look into alpha shapes. But can you show what you already tried? There are numerous methods to do this, some more complicated than others and depending on the data you can choose your method.

Comment: Of course, I will update the question to add a picture of what I tried.

Comment: Also, thank you for the advice. I will take a look at alpha shapes.

Comment: "alpha shapes" are a generalization of "convex hull" to non-convex hulls. ignore that. you'll probably be happy with a convex hull, or some blurring and then thresholding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the yellow blob is slightly different across your images, I recommend you look into either using Morphological Operations, or using Contour Approximation.

I've never used scikit-image, but it appears to have [Morphological functionalities](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html) included.
You can take a look at this [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) for a quick guideline of the different operations.
But I think all you need is to use the ["Opening" operation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.opening) to preprocess your yellow shape; making it smoother and removing the random speckles.

Another approach is by approximating that contour you've extracted to make it smoother. For scikit-image, that is the [`measure.approximate_polygon` function](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#approximate-polygon). Also [another OpenCV tutorial for reference on how Contour Approximation works](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) (the same algorithm as with scikit-image).

Comment: I just tried to play with erosions and dilations, combined with blur effects. Indeed the results are much better. I will also try the approximate_polygon function to see if it can be even better. Thank you !